# Reversing numbers in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I'm trying to figure out how to make it so that the second `s_pin` returns its contents in reverse. So `"Coded Pin"` needs to be `s_pin` in reverse.

```
SELECT s_last||', '|| s_first||LPAD(ROUND(MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE, s_dob)/12,0),22,'*' ) AS "Student Name and Age", s_pin AS "Pin", Reverse(s_pin) AS "Coded Pin"
FROM student
ORDER BY s_last;
```

Output would look like this:
[image]

Comment: `REVERSE` is an undocumented feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oracle's `reverse` function accepts a `char`, not a `number`, so you'd have to convert it:

```
SELECT   s_last||', '|| s_first||LPAD(ROUND(MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE, s_dob)/12,0),22,'*' ) AS "Student Name and Age", 
         s_pin AS "Pin", 
         REVERSE(TO_CHAR(s_pin)) AS "Coded Pin"
FROM     student
ORDER BY s_last;
```

**NOTE** `REVERSE` is an undocumented function. If you are using it in your application, you might have a risk in future, "IF" this feature is removed in a later version that you wish to upgrade to. And it's reasonably likely that they might end up being documented functions in future, who knows. So, use it at your own risk.

Comment: Here we can find an officially supported version: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19624628/a-procedure-to-reverse-a-string-in-pl-sql

Answer (score 2):

`TO_NUMBER (REVERSE( '' || s_pin)) AS "Coded Pin"` should work for you. If you don't need to calculate with *Coded Pin*, you can omit the `TO_NUMBER` function

See documentation of [`TO_NUMBER`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_2117.htm#OLADM695) and [`REVERSE`](http://psoug.org/definition/reverse.htm)

***p.s.*** as per comment: note that the use of `TO_CHAR (s_pin)` is the better option. Thx!

Comment: @Downvoter: can you please explain, why you downvote my answer? It the same, as the accepted answer.

Comment: Just in case you might be thinking, so I am not the down voter. Probably, somebody reading the comments might have got confused. Let me remove my comments, since all the answers are the same. So why a downvote to your answer. Also, OP wants to deliberately use the function. Let me make an up vote to your answer. It would give you +8 points in total.

Comment: By the way, `TO_NUMBER(REVERSE(TO_CHAR(s_pin)))` would be more appropriate. It is better to explicitly convert `number` into `string` to avoid any `implicit data type conversion`.

Answer (score 1):

You're already using the `REVERSE()` function which is supported by Oracle, but it only works on strings, so just convert your `s_pin` value to string first:

```
SELECT s_last||', '|| s_first||LPAD(ROUND(MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE, s_dob)/12,0),22,'*' ) AS "Student Name and Age"
     , s_pin AS "Pin" 
     , REVERSE(TO_CHAR(s_pin)) AS "Coded Pin"
FROM student
ORDER BY s_last;
```